# How to request a page title in a foreign language using wikipedia API

Tags: wikipedia-api

I am trying to use a simple GET request

"[https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=音乐&prop=langlinks&lllimit=500](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=%E9%9F%B3%E4%B9%90&prop=langlinks&lllimit=500)"

but with chinese characters in the title wikipedia can't find the page even though it exists https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%B9%90

I have tried URL encoding the chinese word, I tried both simplified and traditional. I tried giving it unicode in ascii like "\u97f3\u4e50"

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

There are a few things to remember when doing this:

1. You need to use the wikipedia of your target language. so in this case
   zh.wikipedia.org
2. Chinese wikipedia externally displays the charset of the users region (simplified for mainland, standard for Taiwan). But internally it depends on who wrote the article. The title in your api query must be in the original character set of the person who created it.  So for Music, 音樂 will not work and you must use the simplified 音乐. But for Notebook computer the simplified 笔记本 will not work and you must use 筆記本. You have no choice but to try both.  .NET includes a set of methods for converting between the two character sets.